# How to configure settings.py for mongoDB connection in Django we application

Tags: django, mongodb, connection

I am getting following error :

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
  'django_mongodb_engine' isn't an available database backend.
```

And [the official documentation of django says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/databases/):

> Try using `'django.db.backends.XXX'`, where `XXX` is one of: `u'mysql'`, `u'oracle'`, `u'postgresql_psycopg2'`, `u'sqlite3'`

As you can see, there is no `mongodb` in the list in the docs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide more information, so that the community is able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it's probably that `django_mongodb_engine` isn't installed properly:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine
```

See more at: https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/get-started/) for MongoDB and Django connection

Comment: It would be nice to see some explanations or more words about how this would solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer